# Как кликнуть на все ссылки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице имеется много ссылок вида:

```html
<a href="javascript:Begin( '1176892828' );" class="thisLink">Начать</a>
```

Число в скобках у каждой ссылки уникальное, класс "thisLink" использовать нельзя, так как он есть и у ссылок, которые нажимать не надо.  Как кликнуть на все подобные ссылки?

Comment: и как вы хотите определять какие ссылки надо кликнуть а какие нет?

Comment: добавь ещё один класс всем нужным ссылкам, в чём сложность то?

Comment: `$('a').each(function(){
 if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf('javascript:Begin(') != -1) {
  alert($(this).text());
 }
});`  оно?   только вместо `alert($(this).text());` надо `$(this).click()`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский click() на таких ссылках не сработает, на сколько я знаю.

Comment: Я лишь спрошу зачем вам сие деяние? Чего хотите добиться?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev само событие вроде сработает, а вот исполнится ли то, что задумал автор - вопрос другой

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев подозреваю, что автору нужно прокликать множество ссылок на какой-то странице и он хочет автоматизировать свой труд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На сколько я правильно понял, вы хотите вызвать все ссылки, которые содержат функцию Begin. Все довольно просто, получаем все ссылки, отбираем нужные по данным из href и кликаем ссылки, если они содержат данную функцию.

```js
function Begin(number) {
  console.log(number);
}

$('a').each(function() {
  if (this.href.match(/^javascript:Begin\( \'([0-9]+)\' \);$/)) {
    eval(this.href);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:Begin( '1176892828' );" class="thisLink">Link 1</a>
<a href="javascript:Begin( '113453458' );" class="thisLink">Link 2</a>
<a href="/test" class="thisLink">Link 3</a>
<a href="javascript:Begin( '2434534534' );" class="thisLink">Link 4</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Весьма небезопасный вариант, но работает

```
$('a').each(function() {
    hrefVal = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hrefVal.startsWith('javascript:')) {
        eval(hrefVal);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Begin(number) {
  alert(number);
}

$('a').each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf('javascript:Begin(') != -1) {
    eval(this.href);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:Begin( '666' );" class="thisLink">Начать2</a>
<a href="javascript:Begin( '777' );" class="thisLink">Начать3</a>
<a href="#some" class="thisLink">Начать343</a>
<a href="javascript:Begin( '888' );" class="thisLink">Начать4</a>
```

---

javascript

```js
function Begin(number) {
 alert(number);
}

var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (links[i].href.indexOf('javascript:') !== -1) { 
      eval(links[i].href);
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:Begin( '111' );" class="thisLink">Начать2</a>
<a href="javascript:Begin( '222' );" class="thisLink">Начать3</a>
<a href="#some" class="thisLink">Начать3</a>
<a href="javascript:Begin( '333' );" class="thisLink">Начать4</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Begin(number) {
 alert(number);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').each(function(){
    if(-1 !== (this.href).indexOf('javascript:Begin')){
      this.click();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:Begin( '1176892828' );" class="thisLink">Ссылка 1</a>
<a href="javascript:Begin( '1176892821' );" class="thisLink">Ссылка 2</a>
<a href="http://google.com" class="thisLink">Гугл</a>
<a href="javascript:Begin( '1176892822' );" class="thisLink">Ссылка 3</a>
<a href="javascript:Begin( '1176892823' );" class="thisLink">Ссылка 4</a>
<a href="http://yandex.ru" class="thisLink">Яндекс</a>
<a href="javascript:alert( 'FALSE' );" class="thisLink">Javascript</a>
```